# Can Flutter efficiently layout nested lists?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

Can a layout like this be achieved and rendered efficiently in Flutter?

Example:

[image]

Yellow and blue blocks can both be around 30 elements, so I guess something like ListView.builder should be used.

I have tried nesting 2 ListView.builder, the inner with shrinkWrap = true. The yellow block is being built just when is needed, but the blue list, although it has an itemBuilder, it builds all children elements at once, causing performance problems.

```
new ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 20,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int blockIdx) {
    print("Building block $blockIdx");
    return new Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          child: Text("Block $blockIdx"),
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0)
        ),
        ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          itemCount: 30,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int childIdx) {
            print("Building block $blockIdx child $childIdx");
            return Padding(
              child: Text("Child $childIdx"),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 8.0, top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
            );
          },
        );
      ],
    );
  },
);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you tried.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Updated question

Comment: I guess the inner list needs to be built to get the size for the outer list. I don't know how to fix though.

Comment: I have that suspicion also. If that is the case, is it a bug or is it expected behaviour?

Comment: There might be features that would improve behavior I don't know of. I don't have deep knowlege about layout stuff. I think it would be ok to create a Flutter bug report/feature request. Please ensure to create it with a complete but minimal single-file copy-paste runnable reproduction.

Comment: @Martyns did you find any solution, I am also facing this problem right now. My similar kind of widget is taking too long to render. The UI freezes for almost 2-3 seconds.

Comment: @Dhruvgarg You can follow this issue in GH https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26072 What I'm doing is create a single list and render conditionally the headers or inner items. But it's a pain to handle the indexes

Comment: Thanks @Martyns. This seems like the best possible solution, for now, to flatten the nested lists. But like you said it will be a pain to manage indexes and there is no other solution provided in the GH issue you mentioned.

Comment: @Dhruvgarg This is what I'm using at the moment to ease the pain using indexes: https://gist.github.com/davidmartos96/559a246bb4a57c24ab071e6b2cc20b32