# How to show the listview in a listview

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview

I got a problem when I am trying to show the listview in a listview. Right now it shows me the error "Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.". I try to add a container and set up the height to the second listview and it works. But I don't want to restrict the height of the second listview.

```
return new Scaffold(
    body: new Column(
        children: <Widget> [
          new Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget> [
                new Container(), // something else
                new ListView.builder(
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => new MenuCard(menuStore[index]),
                    itemCount: menuStore.length,
                    padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0)
                )
              ]
            )

          )
        ]
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to set the `ListView` property `shrinkWrap` to `true`:

> ```
>   /// Whether the extent of the scroll view in the [scrollDirection] should be
>   /// determined by the contents being viewed.
>   ///
>   /// If the scroll view does not shrink wrap, then the scroll view will expand
>   /// to the maximum allowed size in the [scrollDirection]. If the scroll view
>   /// has unbounded constraints in the [scrollDirection], then [shrinkWrap] must
>   /// be true.
>
> ...
>
>   /// Defaults to false.
>   final bool shrinkWrap;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the Given Error in your code you need to shrinkWrap: true, in `ListView.builder` and `ListView`.

```
 return new Scaffold(
        body: new Column(
            children: <Widget> [
              new Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  shrinkWrap:ture,
                  children: <Widget> [
                    new Container(), // something else
                    new ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap:ture,
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) => new MenuCard(menuStore[index]),
                        itemCount: menuStore.length,
                        padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0)
                    )
                  ]
                )

              )
            ]
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this answer here, Instead of **GridView** you can use **ListView**, also remove the `crossAxisCount` property from **GridView**.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53852317/3811162